# I need a way to filter Soundcloud Stream

Tags: soundcloud

A Radio DJ asked me to have an App or the native Soundcloud Website to filter the stream. Currently he is using Soundcloud App on Mac. He is opening it and sort it out hisself.

In the Stream he don't want to see "DJ Mixes" as he is only interested in material by the artist he follows and not something they mixed.

If it is possible to write this myself in PHP I would do this, but I'm not sure.

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Go check out their APIs.

Comment: yes, possible. good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for a similar solution when I found your question. Further googling brought me to this page and it works like a charm.

http://mixyard.com/